# How to evaluate this limit by using the knowledge of Riemann Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How to evaluate this limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}\int_2^x \frac{1}{\ln t}\,dt$$by using the knowledge of Riemann Integral? Since I am concern about how to find out $F'(x)$ where
$F(x)=\int_2^x \frac{1}{\ln t}\,dt$ such that I can use the L'Hospital rules to derive this limit?

Comment: You could use the Leibniz rule for differentiating the integral.

Answer (score 2):

If we let $F_1(t)=\int \frac{1}{\ln t}dt$, then we have $F'_1(t)=\frac{1}{\ln t}$
Note that $F(x)=F_1(x)-F_1(2)$, so $F'(x)=F'_1(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x}$
Then 
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}\int_2^{x} \frac{1}{\ln t}dt&=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int^x_2 \frac{dt}{\ln t}}{x/\ln x}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1/\ln x}{1/\ln x-1/(\ln x)^2}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-1}\\
&=1
\end{align*}
This agrees with the fact that $\pi (x)\sim \frac{x}{\ln x}\sim Li(x)$ from prime number theorem.

Comment: $F(x)=F_1(x)-F_1(2)$?

Comment: This is just to give intuition from $\int_a^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$. Sorry for the confusion made.

Comment: Now I understand it, thanks.